# How can I prove this logical consequence satisfies the following idempotence rule?

Tags: logic

`If Φ ⊩ ψ for every ψ ∈ Ψ, and Ψ ⊩ χ, then Φ ⊩ χ`

I don't even know how to start, that's what I tried:

"Assuming ψ ∈ Ψ and since Φ ⊩ ψ like Ψ ⊩ χ, then we can assume Φ ⊩ χ"

But of course this isn't proving nothing. I don't know how to formulate something to present as proof!!! Help

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Is that  ⊩ supposed to be $\models$???

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich No, I understand it like "satisfies"

Answer (score 1):

Since $\Psi \vdash \chi$, there are finitely many formulae from $\Psi$, say $\psi_1, \dots, \psi_n \in \Psi$, such that $\vdash \big(\psi_1 \wedge \dots \wedge \psi_n \big) \longrightarrow \chi$.

By assumption you have $\Phi \vdash \psi_i$ for $1\leqslant i \leqslant n$ whence
$\Phi \vdash \psi_1 \wedge \dots \wedge \psi_n$.

Hence, $\Phi \vdash \chi$.

Comment: But the question was about $\models$, not $\vdash$.

Comment: Sorry. I believe the question was meant to be about $\models$; on closer inspection that symbol does not appear...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I wasn't sure, either but I took the bet to interpret "⊩" as $\vdash$.